# How do I include the last element in a range in python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, range

I am using a for loop to add all the elements in a list but when I index (x[-1]) the last element, it still not included. Ex:

```
x=[3,4,5,6]
total=0
for i in range(x[0],x[-1]):
    total= total + i
print(total)
```

The answer I am looking for is 18 but when I run it, it returns 12. (It is still not including the last element). I understand the range function does that but is there a way to still include the last element? Do I have to use a different function? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do - sum all the entries in the list? Just use `sum(x)` for that.

Comment: "Add all elements in a list"? You are not iterate over the list, and besides the range, I do not see any access to the list.

Comment: `range` is returning the a list between 0 and the high number, so you're essentially just adding `[0, 6)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code:

```py
x=[3,4,5,6]
total=0
for i in x:
    total= total + i
print(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

these are three solutions for your usage

```
    x=[3,4,5,6]
    total=0

    #solution 1 :
    total =sum(x)

    #solution 2
    for i in x:
        total= total + i
    print(total)

    #solution 3
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        total= total + x[i]
    print(total)
```

Comment: This isn't a good way to do it. `sum(x)` is the most straightforward, followed by a list comprehension, followed by iterating over the list items directly. Iterating over indexes is not necessary except in certain circumstances.

Comment: thnx, i ve edited my response